# How to check input is only a number, letter and space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write some Javascript to check an input to only allow number and letter and '-' and '_' and **space bar**.

Here is my regular expression

```
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,80}$/;
```

Above regex does not include **space bar**. How can I add space bar condition into my regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this:

```
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){1,80}$/;
```

works.

Maybe you ran into the issue with trying it like this ?

```
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_- ]){1,80}$/;
```

and the regex Parser thought you ment "underscore to spacebar" and not "underscore dash and spacebar ?
(Didn't test that)

### Edit

Did a little testing

```
<script>
alert(/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,80}$/.test("Aa232423"));
// true
alert(/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){1,80}$/.test("Aa232 423"));
// true 
alert(/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_- ]){1,80}$/.test("Aa232423"));
// parser error: invalid range in character set
</script>
```

Do i guess i was right with my assumption ;)

### Secound Edit in Response to OPs Comment:

```
<script>
alert(/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){1,80}$/.test("Aa232-423"));
//true
alert(/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){1,80}$/.test("Aa232-42 3"));
//true
</script>
```

Comment: Even though your `-` is at the end of the set, I'd still suggest you escape it so you can be 100% sure you don't run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the addition casablanca, +1

Comment: and how can replace spacebar with '-'

Comment: how can replace spacebar with '-' i use var text = res_name.val().replace('/\s+/', '-'); it's not work