# user input restriction, (white space, letter, or digit, '-' and '_') c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am wanting to validate user input on a text box by only allowing (white space, letter, or digit, '-' and '_'). I was wondering if someone could help me with that regexp? I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469393/how-to-check-input-is-only-a-number-letter-and-space), but i am trying it and it is not working.

Here is what i am using:

```
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(NameTextBox.Text, "/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -])$/"))
```

Thanks.

**EDIT - New approach.**

I actually decided to go with this instead of regex, any reason why i should not?

```
if (!NameTextBox.Text.All(c=>Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c==' ' || c=='_' || c=='-'))
```

[Reference for the above code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181419/c-newbie-verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters)

Comment: Regex in .NET doesn't require the opening and closing /.  You might also need to escape the final '-' in the character match for the remaining 80 characters (note that this allows a string up to 81 character currently and also requires at least 2 characters)

Comment: why the first [a-zA-Z] group?

Comment: @Serge, OP copied the exact expression from the SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469393/how-to-check-input-is-only-a-number-letter-and-space.

Comment: I decided to go with a different approach after some research. Let me know if there is any reason why i should not do my new attempt. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Comment: @prolink007 Your other approach is not equivalent. I does not limit the input to between 1 and 80 characters.

Comment: @rsbarro, that was not a requirement, i messed up when i copied the regexp from the other link. I will fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want for your regex: `@"^[\w\s-]{1,80}$"`

```
^       match start of string
\w      will match any [A-Za-z0-9_]
\s      will match any whitespace
-       will match the - character
{1,80}  requires between 1 and 80 characters
$       match end of string
```

If by whitespace, you mean you want to match just space (and not tab let's say), switch it to:

`@"^[\w -]{1,80}$"`

Comment: +1, thank you, i have a new approach, please let me know if there is anything wrong with it. =)

Comment: Thanks for all the extra information, accepted your answer. =)

Comment: Thanks. Don't see anything wrong with the other approach in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the forward slash at the start and end, that's a javascript thing.

`"^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]){1,80}$"`

Comment: +1, thank you, i have a new approach, please let me know if there is anything wrong with it. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-_\s])
```

That group matches lower and upper case a-z, 0-9, "-", "_", and whitespace ("\s").

Comment: +1, thank you, i have a new approach, please let me know if there is anything wrong with it. =)